# Matching the string in specific position using unix

Tags: shell, unix

I'm trying to match the string in specific position using substr an running it in a loop

For example my cardfile.txt contains 
`01
02`

My input file is 
`02AAA45678
04BBB04673
01CCC63848
05DDD07494`

I want in the output lines having either 01 or 02 in the first 2 characters as below
`02AAA45678
01CCC63848`

`` for i in `cat cardfile.txt`
do
     awk 'substr($0,1,2) == $i {print} ' input.txt > output.txt
done ``

If I'm trying to run by giving the string in substr directly like "02" it is working properly but if I am giving $i it is not matching the string

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please format your code correctly and give an example with the input and output you expect.

Comment: Click `edit` under your question, then select your code with the mouse and click `{}` in the formatting toolbar. Don't add details in comments - edit your question instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use shell variables in an awk script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script)

Comment: Apart from shell variable usage in awk scripts, also have a look at the best practice for looping over a file line-by-line: [BashFAQ/001](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming your cardfile.txt is supposed to broken up like this:

```
02AAA45678
04BBB04673
01CCC63848
05DDD07494
```

Do you have a requirement to use awk in a loop? How about using grep for it:

```
grep -E '^(01|02)' cardfile.txt
```

if you must use awk as you've done, try like this:

```
for i in `cat cardfile.txt `; do awk 'substr($0,1,2) == "'"$i"'" {print} ' input.txt >> output.txt; done
```

you are running into trouble because of the single quotes and the way your shell does (or does not, in this case) expand $i.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your variable `$i` is surrounded in 'single quotes' which is preventing bash's variable expansion.

This question asks about the same issue and has some good solutions for using bash variables such as your `$i` inside an awk script.

[How do I use shell variables in an awk script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script)